# Логика бронирования квартиры на конкретную дату

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Задача: нужно проверить, может ли человек забронировать квартиру на заданную дату, если может, то сохранить в базе данных, если нет, то ничего не сохранять. Мой вариант кода оказался неправильным, я вообще не понимаю как лучше реализовать этот процесс, даже мыслей нет никаких на этот счёт.
[Code](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src/main/java/task/homerent). Если не понадобится для ответа, то удалю.

```
@PostMapping("/rent")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
public void homeRent(@RequestBody ContractDto contractDto) {
    Contract contract = new Contract();
    House house = houseRepository.findById(contractDto.getId_house()).orElseThrow();
    Set<Contract> temp = house.getContract();
    for(Contract s:temp) {
        System.out.println(s.getStart_date());
        if(s.getStart_date().equals("")) {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113670/discussion-on-question-by-blacit------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Неправильно ты, дядя Фёдор, бутерброд ешь*

Прежде чем кодировать надо нарисовать структуру БД. В данном случае у вас есть таблица `User`, таблица `House` (квартиры) и таблица `Contract` - записи о контрактах. Не углубляясь в дебри [теоремы Бойса-Кодда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B0), более-менее очевидно, что, структура БД приблизительно следующая (в самоочевидном псевдокоде):

```
Contract {
    contractId //первичный ключ
    houseId   //ссылка на арендуемую квартиру
    userId  //ссылка на юзера - кто арендует
    startDate //с какой даты
    endDate //до какой даты
}
```

Теперь пишем SQL запрос на свободность заданной квартиры, примерно так (опять же полупсевдокод):

```
select houseId from Contract where (myEndDate < Contract.startDate or (myStarteDate > Contract.endDate)
```

Запрос выдает список свободных квартир. Ежели в списке указанных квартир значится искомая, значит сохраняем.

Вооружившись таковым знанием уже проще все закодировать можно в виде HQL или программном коде `Hibernate` - что уже и не принципиально.